# Is there a way to directly control the acceleration of a link

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I want to simulate a point mass in Gazebo.
Is there a way to directly control its accelerations (along the x and y axies) ?
In other workds, can we apply forces on links ? or merely on joints ?

And thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2450/is-there-a-way-to-directly-control-the-acceleration-of-a-link/) by [amine23](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/301/amine23/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

yes, you should be able to apply forces on links, [here](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.5.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html) is the API. See which one suits you better, SetForce or AddForce.

A simple code example:

```
this->my_model->GetLink("link_name")->SetForce(math::Vector3(0, 0, 0));
this->my_model->GetLink("link_name")->AddForce(math::Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amine23](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/301/amine23/) on 2013-04-18**:
Thanks!
Well, I want to control it using rospy. I imagine I will have to wirte a plugin using cpp right ? :s

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-18**:
most probably yes, there are good tutorials on gazebosim.org that can show you how to write them.